# FIREMONKEY - Run launcher to start application (OSX)

Tags: macos, delphi, firemonkey

For updating purposes I have created a launcher (Windows/OSX) which starts the main application.

Under Windows it works fine but under OSX the main application is with the following code not started.

```
_system(PAnsiChar('open ' + UTF8String(ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0))+ 'mainapp')));
```

Answer (score 3):

You got the string type casting wrong. This should work:

```
_system(PAnsiChar(UTF8String('open ' + ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0))+ 'mainapp')));
```

Answer (score 0):

If the filename includes spaces, I have found that even the corrected type casting is insufficient, but I have found the following to work correctly for OSX:

`_system(PAnsiChar(UTF8String('open ' + QuotedStr(ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0))+ 'mainapp'))));`

or in my case, the exact code is

`_system(PAnsiChar(UTF8String('open ' + QuotedStr(SaveDialog.Filename))));`